# Linear combination of eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In the textbook "*Molecular Quantum Mechanics*" by Atkins and Friedman [1, p. 11], it says in chapter 1:

> … a general function can be expanded in terms of all the eigenfunctions of an operator, a so-called complete set of functions.

Can ANY function be written as a linear combination of eigenfunctions of ANY operator? I think not.

What are the criteria here for which functions can be written as linear combinations of which operators?

#### References

1. Atkins, P. W.; Friedman, R. *Molecular Quantum Mechanics*, 5th ed.; Oxford University Press: Oxford ; New York, **2011**. ISBN 978-0-19-954142-3.

Comment: you should probably post this on the math stackexchange. The sentence you quoted reads like the author is defining a function that will be analyzed further along in the text.

Comment: In short, any *square-integrable* function can be written that way.

Answer (score 2):

The complete, formal mathematical answer is a bit complex. It might be better to get that discussion from [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

An answer to the world of Chemistry is more straightforward: Yes, for any physically relevant operator and any relevant function, you always can. That’s a fundamental property of quantum mechanics: (functional) states are superpositions of eigenstates.

Comment: Just a short note for OP: in introductory texts on quantum physics & chemistry one can often encounter phrases like "physically relevant" or "well-behaved function" with the actual meaning being "square-integrable function". There are a lot of mathematical nuances and subtleties but to start from square-integrability requirement would be enough.

Comment: That's enough for me! Thank you to Nick, Bob, and Wildcat for answers/comments and to andselisk for editing!